# How can i configure aws sqs to launch a spot ec2 when the queue size is greater than 0

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, video-streaming, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-sqs

I am new to aws services . i am creating a video streaming platform so whenever a user uploads a video a message is added to sqs from s3 event now i have to launch a spot ec2 when the queue size is greater than zero . Can anyone help me for implementing this .

Answer (score 2):

SQS doesn't launch EC2 instances. SQS just stores messages. You need to configure an [EC2 AutoScaling Group](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/auto-scaling-groups.html) to launch the instances. The AutoScaling group will require a CloudWatch metric to use, to determine when it should launch the instances. You would provide a [metric from your SQS queue](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-available-cloudwatch-metrics.html) for that, probably `ApproximateNumberOfMessagesVisible`.